# how to make a dot plot based on existing of a letter or missing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df <- structure(list(Shared = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Door", 
"glass", "Water ", "WC"), class = "factor"), Cond1 = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Hisy", "HIU", "JIS", "NHIS"), class = "factor"), 
    Cond2 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 2L), .Label = c("Hisy", "JIS"
    ), class = "factor"), Cond3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("HIU", 
    "JIS"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I can convert the letters to logical values like this

```
mynew<- t('row.names<-'(!is.na(df[-1]), df$Shared))
```

then I melt it like this

```
mydf2 <- melt(mynew)
```

then I plot it like this

```
ggplot(data = mydf2, aes(x = X1, y = value, fill = X2,colour=X2)) + 
  geom_point()
```

But I want it to be like the following example
I want to plot it in a way that the words become my x axis and cond1, cond2 and cond3 in my y axis.

example like this

[image]

Comment: I don't get the issue. If you want X2 on the x-axis and X1 on the y-axis, just assign them to x and y. Is there more to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @camille said in the comments you are pretty much there (unless we are missing something).

You just need to map X2 to the x-axis and X1 to the y-axis. The only step you can take first is to filter out from your data frame the cases where the column `value` is FALSE.

I tried to format the plot so it looks as close as possible to your example.

```
# remove rows where value == FALSE
mydf2 <- melt(mynew) %>% filter(value) 

# create plot (in my case `melt` named the variables Var1 and Var2 instead of X1 and X2)
ggplot(data = mydf2, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1)) + 
  geom_point(fill='blue', colour='black', shape=21, size=3) + 
  scale_y_discrete(position = 'right') +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),
                     axis.title = element_blank(),
                     axis.line = element_line(),
                     panel.border = element_blank())
```

Hope this helps

[image]